# PineScript barssince( strategy.position_size > 0) not working correctly?

Tags: pine-script

Pretty sure there is a PS bug here.

On my screen, I can see that I have a position open, but could not get barSincePosOpen to increase in value.

But when I changed:

barssince(strategy.position_size > 1)
to
barssince(strategy.position_size < 1)

then it actually started incrementing as it should have.[image]

```html
barSincePosOpen = barssince(strategy.position_size < 1)

plot(barSincePosOpen, "Bars Since Pos Open", color.green)
```

I'm basically trying to build a system using MA's, if the price is above the MA then long, and use that same MA as a trailing stop loss.

But I want it to exit at the highest point of that MA, so even if the MA moves down, which if often does, without crossing, I'd the MA be replaced as in old_ma := over ride old_ma with the highest MA value since strategy.open_trades > 0

Can't seem to get this right though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine. `barSincePosOpen = barssince(strategy.position_size < 1)` will start counting bars when a transition occurs between a short or no position, to a long, so it will track the number of bars the long position is held.

To track the highest point the MA reaches during the trade, you will need to track it from the moment you enter a trade. If you have an `enterLong` variable that's true when a trade must be entered, you could use code like:

```
ma = sma(close, 50)
var float stop = na
stop := enterLong and not enterLong[1] ? ma : max(stop, ma)
```

Comment: Thank you ! Appreciate the input, will review carefully